# Getting list of cities and countries from a SQL Table

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL table where in each row I store the country and the city of a things location. For example:

```
record1, New York, USA
record2, Rome, Italy
record3, Milano, Italy
record3, Birghiman, UK 
record4, London, UK
record5, London, UK
record6, London, UK
record7, Birmingham, UK
```

I would like to generate a list that is ordered by country and city, and each city show up only once in the result.

I would like to know how to solve this in SQL and Linq To SQL in an elegant way.

Comment: Please clarify what "there is only one city form the table" means, as I cannot parse this phrase.

Comment: I noticed that in SQL I can solve this the following way: 

SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT city, country FROM table ORDER BY country

It would be still nice to know the Linq way though

Comment: Adding the "Top 100 Percent" is a way to force an ORDER BY into a view. Most DBAs and everyone at M$ would discourage this. If you are saving this as a view, put the Order By on the call to the view. If you are not, you don't need to Top 100 Percent.

Comment: @gyurisc, a) distinct is slow, Joel's solution should be a faster alternative b) you don't need to use the TOP clause there, that's only if you're limiting the rows returned (IE ...TOP 10 rows...)

Comment: When running the execution plan....distinct and group by are identical.

Comment: @Bill: it's also added automatically in many places by enterprise manager.  Enough so that it can be a pain to get rid of and many who don't know better just assume they need it.  So glad Management Studio doesn't just include that any more.

Comment: @Nathan, Where can I find the Joel solution that you are referring to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select distinct country, city
from <Table>
order by country, city;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(record) AS record, City, Country
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY City, Country
ORDER BY Country, City
```

Comment: This will probably be a far faster option to the distinct option.

Comment: @CSharpAtl: you can't return the 'record' column with the distinct.

Comment: @Joel: true....but I did not take the record number as a literal column, if it is, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this with Linq as well. It seems to be working ok. Not sure about the performance though

```
        var result = from p in table
                     group p by p.country into country_group
                     select new
                     {
                         country = country_group.Key,
                         cities = from ci in country_group
                                  group ci by ci.city into city_group
                                  select new { city = city_group.Key, cig = city_group }
                     };                          


        foreach(var co in result)
        {
            string country = co.country; 

            foreach(var ci in co.cities)
            {
                string city = ci.city;
            }
        }
```